# Import JSON to Google Sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, import, json

I am using Apps Script in Google Sheets to import JSON from Google Analytics. I have previously used the [ImportJSON function](http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json) to easily get the JSON from an open API just using `=ImportJSON(url)` within a cell. Because I am using Apps Script to authorise the Analytics API stuff (this all works fine), I am also using it to insert the JSON data into my sheet. ImportJSON returns a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers. However, I am having difficulty getting the range of the data so that I can add the values to the sheet.

This is what I have:

```
function makeRequest() {
  var analyticsService = getAnalyticsService();
  var apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=removed&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3AuniquePageviews&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%40%2FKnowledgeBank%2FFactsheetForFarmers.aspx&max-results=10&access_token=' + analyticsService.getAccessToken()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var jsonData = ImportJSON(apiUrl);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(jsonData.length,jsonData[0].length);
  cell.setValues(jsonData);
}
```

The error I get is **Incorrect range height, was 3 but should be 1**

Comment: try var cell = sheet.getRange(1, 1, jsonData.length,jsonData[0].length);

Comment: With that, the error I get is **Incorrect range width, was 25 but should be 27**

Comment: I don't do much JSON conversion, but I thought ImportJSON is a spreadsheet function (formula). To Parse JSON in javascript (GAS) you need JSON.parse I think. See also: https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a#.jpob8ahnd and here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658980/import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Also check out: https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1442370

Comment: Oh yeah, I am thinking about this a stupid way round! Thanks, will use JSON.parse

Comment: I have used this https://gist.github.com/varun-raj/5350595a730a62ca1954

Comment: Check: [`ImportJSON` at GitHub](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) for the `ImportJSON()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JPV pointed out, the line

```
var jsonData = ImportJSON(apiUrl);
```

is not valid in Apps Script (unless you have defined `ImportJSON` function somewhere). To fetch something from an external URL in Apps Script, one uses [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). So the line could be

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl).getContentText());
```

After this, jsonData is a JavaScript *object* parsed from the JSON string returned by the server. To import it in a spreadsheet, one has to create a double array suitable for passing to `setValues`. How to do this depends on the structure of the object.

The [pullJSON gist](https://gist.github.com/varun-raj/5350595a730a62ca1954) that you referenced gives a simple model of this process, which works when jsonData is already an array.  But different APIs work differently: for example, Stack Exchange API returns an object with several "wrapper" properties, one of which is `items` that holds an array of objects of interest. So in this case one would loop over the elements of `jsonData.items`, extracting the properties of each object in the array and pushing them into a double array.

Answer (score -2):

It is also possible to pull data from a [JSON file to Google Sheets](https://blog.coupler.io/how-to-import-json-to-google-sheets-without-coding/) without using Google Apps Script.
What you need to do, is to install add-on, then fill out the fields, set up an automatic data schedule and run it for the first time (to make sure it fetches all data correctly). I attach screenshot of the form itself [image: screenshot of the required parameters]