# What's the best way to upload a million row spreadsheet as Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-drive, google-docs, microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with over a million rows that I would like to have as a Google sheet.

I tried uploading the file as a CSV to my Google drive, which worked.  Then I tried opening it as a Google sheet, but that took over 2 days and didn't open.

I tried copying and pasting from the CSV into the Google sheet.  The page keeps saying it is unresponsive, I say wait and that loop continues.  I'm not sure if this is the right approach or how long to expect to wait.

Can Google sheets access my hard drive?  Is there some code I could write in Google sheets to upload the records one at a time?

I'm willing to wait as long as it takes.  Maybe there's a better approach I am missing?

I can code in VBA.  Is there some way excel could write to a Google sheet?

Ultimately, I would like to access the data in a Google ad script.  I saw Google ad scripts can access Google sheets hence my approach.  But, if there is another Google cloud solution I can upload the data to, I am also open to that.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import JSON to Google Sheet using Google Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88362/import-json-to-google-sheet-using-google-apps-script)

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Questions on this site should be specific (avoid including multiple questions in one post, even if they are rhetorical,),should avoid asking for opinions and it's recommended that they include a brief description of the search/research efforts, and should hot ask for software recommendations Ref [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets has hard-and-fast limitations. One of them is that no spreadsheet may have more than five million cells total among all sheets/tabs. If you are trying to upload 1M rows, and those rows each contain more than 5 cells each (which is likely), you'll have exceeded this number (in fact, 1M rows with 5 cells each completely maxes the space limitation).

There is currently no workaround, no way to "buy more space," etc.

I have been working with spreadsheets since they were first introduced to the world, and I have yet to see a case where 1M rows in one sheet was necessary. It almost surely points to keeping information you don't need or grouping together information that would best be divided/subdivided into more meaningful chunks.

By way of a simple example, suppose you had 1M rows of data corresponding to customers who bought products. Did all 1M people buy these products in the same year, or could you have separate spreadsheets per year? Did they all live in one state, or could the data have been separated to different spreadsheets by state?

You can then make dashboards that can pull from other spreadsheets to show you what you want to know. For instance, if you separated data by year into different spreadsheets, you could have a dashboard in a separate spreadsheet that could access spreadsheets from all other years to show you *select information* (e.g., name, email, item purchased?) for customers from the last three years who live in Florida (or who are age 30 - 50, or who bought more than five items per year, etc.).

Another thing to consider. It sounds like you're currently using spreadsheets more as a database or databank. And while spreadsheets can and do serve this purpose, if you will have massive amounts of data, you may want to look into database tools specifically designed to handle that volume and then integrate those with Google Sheets for further processing.